# Measure code timing in python. What did I wrong?

Tags: python, time

```
import time
s = time.time()
def insertionSort(alist):
    for index in range(1, len(alist)):

        currentvalue = alist[index]
        position = index

        while position > 0 and alist[position - 1] > currentvalue:
            alist[position] = alist[position - 1]
            position = position - 1

        alist[position] = currentvalue
alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
insertionSort(alist)
print (time.time() - s) # Result 0.0
```

I look up for time module, but is hard to me as newbie to read it. I already searching an answer what comes up it's measure the start of code and end of a code. And the result is 0.0. Please help me with this.

Comment: It finished too fast to be registered; try running the sort several times (making sure to initialize the array *inside* the loop). Also, use [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) to measure performance. (Or [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).)

Comment: What did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with how you use `time.time`.

The reason that `0.0` was printed is the code ran so quickly that the timer did not change at all.

To illustrate my point, I have looped your code for 1000 times.

```
import time
s = time.time()
def insertionSort(alist):
    for index in range(1, len(alist)):

        currentvalue = alist[index]
        position = index

        while position > 0 and alist[position - 1] > currentvalue:
            alist[position] = alist[position - 1]
            position = position - 1

        alist[position] = currentvalue
for x in xrange(1000):
    insertionSort([54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20])
e = time.time()
print (e - s)
```

Output:

```
0.00600004196167
```

There is a bulti-in library called `timeit` which is useful for this situation if you are interested in code performance.

```
import timeit
t = timeit.Timer("insertionSort([54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20])", "from __main__ import insertionSort")
time = t.timeit(1000)
print(time)
```

Output:

```
0.00587430725292
```

Comment: Yesss! Thanks a lot Alex!